# Make an non-electron window parent to an electron app

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, electron

I want my electron browser window to be child of the desktop window handle (hWND) in windows 10 which you can get from the [c++ win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/). So I need to create a BrowserWindow or somehow make the desktop window handle parent to the electron browser window.

I wasn't able to make the window parent to the desktop window handle via the [SetParent function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent). This is how I tried to do it: `SetParent(electronHWND, GetDesktopWindow());`.

Maybe electron is setting parent automatically?